# Insert into SQL database 2 lines with an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, odbc

I can insert into my database. Except I need to modify the code.

I have a tables that contains the labor and part numbers and cost in a mysql database. I am then inserting it into a SQL database.

The SQL database display is not able to be changed. We perform service work and there are two lines for every product we fix.

Number 1 Parts Line, Number 2 Labor line. I am able to get this information and shove it into the SQL database one line at a time but, I am trying to figure out how to do it within an array.

So Product 1 has part line and labor line. Then Product 2 has a part line and labor line and so forth.
[Example SQL Database View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFsG6.png)

So this is causing some issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide both the queries you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the 'causing some issues' might be, as you don't say, but you CAN insert two items in one statement (assuming that you have the data for both rows), if it might help the 'issue':

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, ...)
VALUES (data1, data2, data3, ...),(data1, data2, data3, ...);
```

The first value set can be the parts info, the second value set can be the labor info.

Comment: I have 5-10 products. Each with a part and labor line. Can this be done with starting an array above the insert and closing after the insert? Then I could put both line as noted above. I did try with the comma but this is inserting into SQL not MYSQL using ODBC and not sure if it has an issue with it.

Comment: But you have a MySQL tag on you question? ... So I assumed the ODBC was inserting to MySQL. So what is the actual DB sql server, or ?

Comment: I am pulling data from mysql and inserting into SQL.

Comment: Doh!, you said that in the question! The comma value groups should not cause trouble based on other sources. However, you will not be able to simply pass an array in the groupings without other handling. That being said, are you using ODBC for MySQL? If so, not to send you down a 'rabbit hole', but could  [Linked Server](http://www.thebuttonfactory.nl/?p=2204) be an option for you with? It seems possible to do INSERT INTO your_sql  using a MySQL SELECT query, which could avoid the array handling by using a query across data sources instead. There may be other aspects unknown to me, though.